# What is contained in Android's init on initrd.img?

Tags: android, boot, initrd

I unpacked the initrd.img with `cat initrd.img | gunzip | cpio -vid` and then there's an executable called `init` which I think is the first thing the kernel runs. However, what does it do? Is there an example of one that I can look on google AOSP source so I have an idea? This one is likely modified by Xiaomi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a brief explanation of android bootup and init

- On android bootup , the bootloader locates and loads the linux
  kernel. The linux kernel boots into the userspace from the
  kernelspace using the initramfs functionality in the kernel.
- The ramdisk is essentially a disk image that contains everything
  associated with the root filesystem of the device, essentially the '/
  ' directory. The initramfs mounts the ramdisk into memory ( a
  temporary filesystem ) .
- Later, initramfs looks into the memory and loads and executes the
  **init** binary. The ramdisk.img has C files which configure what init
  does .
- Init is the first process executed in the userspace which is
  responsible for getting the core userspace functionality up and
  running.
- **initrc** files , the ones responsible for configuring what init
  actually does have set of instructions with scripts which run on
  certain event triggers ( such as on init, on fs, on boot).
- init **keeps on running** and monitors the system for certain changes in
  the properties (triggers). Instructions associated with these
  triggers are executed upon change in the properties. (Such as USB Debugging on/off)
- Additionally, init executes native processes called **services**
  which are essentially daemons such as installd, logd, ueventd etc. init also restarts services that may exit/killed. Daemon processes
  have limited ability to communicate to each other and use local
  sockets to read and write data from.

To read further you can refer [here](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/kernel-newbie-corner-initrd-and-initramfs-whats/) and this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5SQP0qfUDjI)